# Is this behavior of this software malware-like?

Tags: windows, updates, malware

I use Signal, and have been using [Signal Desktop](https://signal.org/blog/signal-desktop/) on Windows for a while.  The software seems to work fine, but I take issue with its aggressive stance towards updating itself.  It's very slimey; that is to say I wind up arguing with the software, and it does what it wants, rather than let me do what I want it to do.

Specifically, when Signal Desktop detects an update, Windows makes a ding, the icon in the start menu starts flashing, and a nag window pops up, with the option to update now or later.  The nag window will return after a few minutes if it is dismissed*.

If I click on the close [X] button (which in Windows means to dismiss something without doing anything), the whole application will close, a service will download the update (or it will have already downloaded it) **and it will start to update itself**.  Often this takes several minutes, the shell explorer will flash, and the system will not be stable/usable during this time: **it looks like my PC is having a seizure**.  There is sufficient time for me to open task manager, find the process, and kill it.  There is no other way to opt out of an update.  Even killing it like this, when the software starts again, it will start its update routine.

If I click on the later button, the popup goes away, and the window will return later.

**The only softwares I am familiar with that uses these heavy handed and shady tactics are** Windows, and **malware, malvertising, etc.**  I understand the need to update software, but **removing user control is a bad idea**.  Being underhanded about forcing a software process and half-lying about it is **not good software design**, nor a best practice in *any industry* (except sales?).

**Is this behavior like malware?**  Or is it the SJW-knows-better mentality of the left coast (including Silicon Valley) enforcing its opinions on the rest of the world, like we are currently seeing in the social media space?

Comment: You are using beta-test software which can still change. Why don't you [Contact Signal Support](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misunderstanding the situation.  From the main page of [Signal's official website](https://signal.org):

> Signal messages and calls are always end-to-end encrypted and painstakingly engineered to keep your communication safe. We can't read your messages or see your calls, and no one else can either.

In short, Signal is an *encrypted* messaging service. And when it comes to encryption, using outdated code can either prevent you from connecting to that service or, worse, allow others to break your communications (because they have figured out how to exploit the older code/encryption methods).

So while I would agree generally that not being particularly forthcoming about updates (and/or forcing them on users) is poor design, this isn't about needless UX changes, advertising or political ideology. It's about keeping your communications *safe*.

*Remedies*

- If you like Signal and wish to continue using it, then you should submit feedback to Signal explaining your issue(s) and hopefully they will change things in the future.
- If you don't trust Signal, then don't use it. There are other encrypted messaging services available.